# Обращение к массиву record

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbopascal

Запись состоит из двух полей

```
Type
things = record
name: string[12];
price: longint;
end;
```

Записи хранятся в массиве, их несколько

```
arr: array[1..N] of things;
```

Можно ли сразу обратиться ко всей строке, а не таким образом как я написал ниже?

```
writeln(arr[1].name, arr[1].price) // получилось только так

arr[1] // пробовал такой вариант, но не выходит
```

Пример свапа (меняю местами поочередно сначала поле строкового типа, затем целочисленного)

```
                if arr[j].price < arr[j + 1].price then
           begin
                temp_str := arr[j].name;
                arr[j].name := arr[j + 1].name;
                arr[j + 1].name := temp_str;

                temp_int := arr[j].price;
                arr[j].price := arr[j + 1].price;
                arr[j + 1].price := temp_int;
           end;
```

Comment: к какой "всей строке". Нет "всей" строки, есть отдельные поля структуры. Что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Igor, обратиться к двум полям одновременно

Comment: Что вы понимаете под этим? Привидите пример того как это должно было бы работать и для чего, с какой целью

Comment: @Kromster, например поменять местами строки массива, при каком либо условии. Пример добавил. Цель - уменьшить размер кода

Comment: Вы можете написать так `temp_thing := arr[j]; arr[j] := arr[j + 1]; arr[j + 1] := temp_thing;`

Comment: @Kromster, да. Я понял в чем была проблема, той самой временной переменной я давал не тот тип, и поэтому была ошибка в типе и невозможность обратиться напрямую к элементам массива

Comment: @Kromster, а если выводить поля на консоль к примеру, то только таким образом можно **writeln(arr[i].name, arr[i].price)** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function ThingsToString(const aThings: things): string;
begin
  Result := aThings.name + ',' + IntToStr(aThings.price);
end;

writeln(ThingsToString(arr[1]));
```